# Returning response from factory to controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a **factory** that request user data via an api call:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('UserApi', function($auth,Account){
        return {
            getProfile: function()
                {
                 Account.getProfile()
                    .then(function(response){
                        return response.data; ----> returning json data ok!!
                    });

                }
        }   
});
```

But when i call the function in controller, it return me **undefined**

```
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($rootScope,$state,$window,$document,$scope,$filter,$resource,cfpLoadingBar,$translate,UserApi){

$scope.user = function(){
        UserApi.getProfile().then(function(data){
            $scope.currentUser = data;
        })
    }
console.log($scope.user()); ----> undefined
});
```

account factory:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('Account', function($http){
        return {
            getProfile: function(){
                 return $http.get('/api/me');
            }
        }
    });
```

The error that log in console is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

---

### EDIT

The only available solution is to set the `response.data` to `$rootScope.user` in which the data will be available across the controllers.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('UserApi', function($auth,Account,$rootScope){
        return {
            getProfile: function()
                {
                 Account.getProfile()
                    .then(function(response){
                        $rootScope.user = response.data; ----> returning json data ok!!
                    });
                    return $rootScope.user;
                }
        }   
});
```

Comment: What is Account? Can you post the code for account?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**:

You get undefined. Because:

- there isn't `return` in `$scope.user`
- your `console.log($scope.user($scope.user())` works only initial time.
- there is time delay for getting data from `UserApi.getProfile()`
- Also, your codes have some mistakes:

I can suggest that:

- Don't use your `console.log($scope.user())` initial time.
- Or, You should get all data initial time when factory created. Then, you use `UserApi.data` in your controller.(But, there is time delay. You may get success data, if request return response before from loading of your controller).

.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('UserApi', function ($auth, Account) {
        var data;
        Account.getProfile().then(function (response) {
            data = response.data;
        });
        return {
            data: data
        }
    });

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function ($rootScope, $state, $window, $document, $scope, $filter, $resource, cfpLoadingBar, $translate, UserApi) {
    console.log(UserApi.data);
});
```

Comment: How to fetch data from controller then?

Comment: Ok, I suggest other solution(i will edit my answer). I just fix your issue

Comment: @novavent. why do you need `$scope.user();`

Comment: Still the console log undefined

Comment: I need $scope.user so i can access them all over the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return the data after the request is completed successfully. But, since this is an ajax call we don't know when it will be completed (Basically, runs on a different thread.). There are two ways you can resolve this.

1 - Just return the call like so.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('UserApi', function($auth,Account){
        return {
            getProfile: function(){
                     return Account.getProfile(); // return call and resolve in controller.                   

                }
        }   
});
```

2 - You can use promise ($q)

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('UserApi', function($auth,Account, $q){
        return {
            getProfile: function(){
                     var deferred = $q.defer();
                     Account.getProfile()
                       .success(function(data){
                           deferred.resolve(data);
                     });                   
                     return deferred.promise; // just return the promise
                }
        }   
});
```

and in your controller just have the following.

```
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($rootScope,$state,$window,$document,$scope,$filter,$resource,cfpLoadingBar,$translate,UserApi){

    $scope.user = function(){
        UserApi.getProfile().then(function(data){
            $scope.currentUser = data;
            console.log($scope.currentUser);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It still log undefined!!

Comment: `console.log($scope.user());` => `console.log($scope.currentUser)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `getProfile` method should return a promise (not undefined like it's doing in your code):

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('UserApi', function($auth,Account){
        return {
            getProfile: function()
                {
                 return Account.getProfile()
                    .then(function(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
                }
        }   
});
```

then in controller you should use `then` callback:

```
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function ($rootScope, $state, $window, $document, $scope, $filter, $resource, cfpLoadingBar, $translate, UserApi) {

    $scope.user = function () {
        UserApi.getProfile().then(function (data) {
            $scope.currentUser = data;
            console.log($scope.currentUser);
        })
    };
});
```

Also make sure you understand the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code, and why `console.log($scope.user())` makes no sense in this case: response if not yet available when you try to log it. Instead you provide a callback to be called when data has come.